# c# MVC5 @Html.EditorFor datepicker never displays the value

Tags: date, razor, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5, display

Sorry to bother but I've been headbanging on this topic for 8 hours
tried all the suggested solutions here and there and nothing changes (in good).
If someone could help... pleaaaase ...

I have a view supposed to display a datepicker without the hours

```html
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDateFilter, new { @class = "form-control datepicker" , @value = "'" + Model.OrderDateFilter.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'"})
```

and the display is always THIS
[error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxqZp.png)

HTML result

```html
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field OrderDateFilter must be a date." data-val-required="Le champ OrderDateFilter est requis." id="OrderDateFilter" name="OrderDateFilter" type="date" value="09/02/2023">
```

So whatever the value it is never displayed except when I click the datepicker and choose a new date, I post the form to the controler, value is kept, processed and is correctly set back to 'value' but never shown

I've tried to TextBoxFor options with @type='date', etc...
Tryed use boostrap datepicker but it's obviously ugly and I could never get rid of the hour 00:00:00 format always displayed by default

Here's the Model part for this date filter (if I don't add the 2 first Annotations it's the same)

```html
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime OrderDateFilter { get; set; } //---
```

Answer (score 0):

18/03/2022 - EDIT
the date format in model etc.. MUST BE yyyy-MM-dd (because I don't need hours/minutes..) and no other format is possible. The datepicker displayed by Razor will pick the browser default culture to display the user's local format and will transate to yyyy-MM-dd in the controler etc..
then it works without jQuery datepicker or others

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).